# Rails: How do I create links like "mysite.com/fFD2Zad" instead of "mysite.com/?var=fFD2Zad"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want users to have codes to invite other users to the website. I know how I could generate random strings but how can I make it so that each user has a link such as "mysite.com/fFD2Zad" that uses the code instead of having a bulky link like "mysite.com/?var=fFD2Zad"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/:invitation_code', to: 'users#welcome'
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
    p params
  end
end
```

Check `yourserver.com/fFD2Zad`

```
#=> {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"welcome", "invitation_code"=>"fFD2Zad"}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the lowest priority route in the end of `routes.rb`:

```
get '/:user_code', to: 'users#profile', user_code: /[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}/
```

And process it in your controller:

```
def profile
  # => params[:user_code]
  ...
end
```